# Как разложить такой объект?

Tags: javascript

Имею объект вида `[{num: 10}]`. Как доствать "10", оператор разложения "..." уберет только один слой.

Comment: Приведенный пример имеет синтаксическую ошибку: _Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '}'_

Comment: Объект в JS имеет вид {key: value}

Comment: Синтаксическая ошибка никуда не делась

Comment: @azlov, не всегда, может быть краткая запись `{keyValue}` эквивалентная `{keyValue: keyValue}`

Comment: @Grundy если keyValue переменная

Comment: @azlov, можно и так сказать

Comment: Что значит _оператор разложения "..." уберет только один слой._?

Comment: @Grundy он уберает только массив, а мне необходимо убрать и массив и объект

Comment: Он ничего не убирает. Пока непонятно что и где ты хочешь получить. По предоставленному коду тебе достаточно получить нулевой элемент массива и получить свойство `num`, но в зависимости от реальной задачи и имеющегося кода решения могут быть различными

Comment: @Grundy, блин... Действительно.

Answer (score 1):

Если Вы хотите достать num, то можно воспользоваться деструктуризацией так:

```
let arr = [{num: 10}];
let [ { num } ] = arr;
console.log(num);
```